# Can a Google App Engine datastore be shared between Python 2 and Python 3 microservices?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-2.x

I have a single-service application running on the Python 2 standard environment on Google App Engine, with data stored in the App Engine datastore.

Is it possible to setup a second service/module with the Python 3 standard environment, which has access to the same datastore?

I have tried that without success. The Python 2 code uses the old [`db`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.db) module to access data and the Python 3 code uses the [`google-cloud-datastore`](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-datastore/) library. When writing to the datastore from the Python 3 code the code fails on the production environment with the error `google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Missing or insufficient permissions.`, despite the [docs saying that it should just work](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html#client-provided-authentication) without any special configuration. In the development environment, with the datastore emulator, I've not managed to connect the services to the same datastore project ID.

Here's the Python 3 code that fails:

```py
import datetime
import os

from flask import Flask
from google.cloud import datastore

PROJECT = 'my-project'  # Not my actual value

IS_DEV = os.environ.get('GAE_ENV', '') != 'standard'

if IS_DEV:
    os.environ.setdefault('DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST', 'localhost:8081')
    os.environ.setdefault('DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID', PROJECT)

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/test_write/')
def test_write():
    client = _get_datastore_client()
    key = client.key('TestEntity')
    entity = datastore.Entity(key)
    entity.update({
        'created': datetime.datetime.now()
    })

    client.put(entity)  # <--- this fails ---

    return f'Created {entity.key.id}'


def _get_datastore_client() -> datastore.Client:
    if IS_DEV:
        client = datastore.Client(_http=requests.Session())
    else:
        client = datastore.Client()
    return client
```

Comment: Is the Python 3 app in the same project as the Python 2 app and the datastore instance?

Comment: Yes, they are both deployed in the same project. That should make them use the same datastore instance as well, right?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: It looks like you are using a different service account for your python 3 app and that service account doesn't have access to Cloud Datastore.  Ensure your service accounts have editor access for Cloud Datastore.

Comment: That is indeed the case, but the service account used in the Python 3 service has the _owner_ role for the project which should be sufficient as far as I understand the documentation. I'll tinker with the permissions to see if that's the issue.